# Устраревшие методы

Tags: android, java

java считает эти методы устаревшими: showDialog, onCreateDialog. Есть ли похожие методы вместо этих?

Кусок кода с этим методами:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int DIALOG_TIME = 1;
    int myHour = 14;
    int myMinute = 35;
    TextView tvTime;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    }

    public void onclick(View view) {
        showDialog(DIALOG_TIME);
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == DIALOG_TIME) {
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, myHour, myMinute, true);
            return tpd;
        }
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }

    OnTimeSetListener myCallBack = new OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            myHour = hourOfDay;
            myMinute = minute;
            tvTime.setText("Time is " + myHour + " hours " + myMinute + " minutes");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/alertdialog.php используйте AlertDialog.Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо них следует использовать `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел уже. Но еще не знаю, что это. Не поможете для моего примера переделать?